# Try Catch no funciona en PHP con PDO

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente bloque de código para ejecutar un insert, el insert me esta arrojando un error de que un campo que no incluyo en mi insert no tiene un valor por defecto (utilice la instrucción $stmt->errorInfo).

el Código es el siguiente:

```
try {
        $db=SPDO::singleton();
        $stmt=$db->prepare("insert into TB_CHEQUE(iChq_Ide,iChq_Cta,sChq_Num,iChq_Uso,dChq_Fem,dChq_Fco,iChq_IdeRes,iChq_IdeRef,dChq_Imp,dChq_Sal,iChq_Emi,sChq_Est) values(Null,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'V');");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$iChq_Cta,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$sChq_Num,PDO::PARAM_STR,12);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$iChq_Uso,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$dChq_Fem);
        $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
        $stmt->bindParam(4,$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',$dChq_Fco);
        $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
        $stmt->bindParam(5,$fecha,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(6,$iChq_IdeRes,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(7,$iChq_IdeRef,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(8,$dChq_Imp,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(9,$dChq_Imp,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(10,$iChq_Emi,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Falló la Ejecución: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Por que no funciona el Try Catch?, utilizando el ($stmt->errorInfo) puedo detectar el error pero la verdad estar haciendolo cada vez que ejecuto una sentencia en la base de datos no me parece lo mas adecuado, gracias por su tiempo.

Agregando info: cuando digo que no funciona me refiero a que no muestra ningún error, en ese insert me faltan unos campos que no tienen valores por defecto (utilice la instrucción $stmt->errorInfo). se supone que el try catch deberia capturar el error y mostrarlo.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no funciona? ¿No está entrando al `catch` e imprimiendo el error? ¿O a caso esperas otro tipo de comportamiento?

Comment: Revisastes que el error sea el que estas capturando??

Comment: si lo revise por eso es que digo que le falta un campo que no tiene valor por defecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método predeterminado para manejar [los errores de PDO](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php) es `PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT`, que nunca te va a tirar una excepción. Tienes que definir el modo `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` tú mismo al abrir la conexión.

Ignoro lo que hay en tu singleton pero debieras poder hacerlo con:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: Eso era, soy nuevo en PHP y no sabia de esa opción para mostrar los errores acabo de probarlo en mi código y ahora si me el try Catch me captura el error. Gracias amenadiel. problema resuelto.

Comment: como se finaliza la pregunta ??? disculpen pero soy nuevo por aca.

Comment: @Emersoft tienes que marcar el cheque que esta abajo de las flechas en esta respuesta para darla por aceptada. Saludos.